# Angular: display a div depending on a Select inside a ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

Here is my problem,

I'd like to display a div depending of what happens in a select which is in a ngfor loop. I guess it will be more easy to understand with a few lines of code

```
<tr>
    <td>
         {{ car.price }}
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="brands" placeholder="select">
            <option [value]="null">Select</option>
            <option *ngFor="let brand of brands"
            (click)="onSelect(brand,car);" [value]="brand.id"> 
                                    {{ brand.name }}
                                </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="if brand is not selected"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I try to create an array of boolean and write *ngif="display[i]" but it didn't work.
What would be the best solution ?

Comment: What does `onSelect` do?

Answer (score 0):

Assign an `ngModel` to the select.

```
<select name="brands" placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedBrand">
(...)
<div *ngIf="!selectedBrand"></div>
```

(And declare `selectedBrand` property inside the component. something like `public selectedBrand: string;`.)